# Compiling just some parts of mscorlib.dll from Mono repository

Tags: c#, dll, compilation, unity-game-engine, mscorlib

I'm developing a mobile game with unity3d and everything works fine with my code :)

When i try to build the game for browser, unity3d uses a stripped version of mscorlib.dll so my code won't find references and doesn't compile. I thought to add manually to the project the references that is missing in form of a compiled .dll, by using mono opensource repository.

I already used this approach with System.Runtime.Serialization.dll succesfully, but i'm not so fluent and skilled with C#

For example, what i need is a dll that contains System.Reflection workspace. Is it possible?

PS: keep in mind that i can only use 2.0 version of mono/c#

Thank you.

Comment: That's not going to work.  They removed reflection because it doesn't make much sense in JS; not because they were trying to annoy you.

Comment: so i have to write specific code to save to disk and instantiate from disk object data :\ awful :\

Comment: Which part refers to JS?  Also what exactly isn't working?  In Unity 4.2.0f4 I have no issues building several scripts using System.Reflection to parse field information.  That's with a browser build.

Comment: this is the error that is actually giving.. i don't know what to do to solve it.

Internal compiler error. See the console log for more information. output was:
Unhandled Exception: System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: The classes in the module cannot be loaded.
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.Assembly:GetTypes (bool)
  at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.CSharp.RootNamespace.ComputeNamespaces (System.Reflection.Assembly assembly, System.Type extensionType) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 .........

Comment: @Lotti Ah, is this 3rd party code you're trying to reflect?  Not that this solves your problem but [Unity is pretty explicit](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/SecuritySandbox.html) about removing reflection for private/internal methods you didn't write, assuming that's the case here.

Comment: i think that for web players i have to rewrite code that is blocked for security reasons or stripped away from mscorlib.dll

Thank everyone anyway.